# Windows machine not waking up when using a KVM switch

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, kvm-switch

I have a Windows laptop which I can sleep and wake up using my keyboard and mouse.

I recently added a KVM switch so that I can use the same resources for my work machine as well. However now, if I were to sleep the Win10 Machine, switch away, switch back, I am unable to wake it up using my keyboard or mouse, and have to use the laptops power button. It IS still able to wake up if I were to put it to sleep but NOT switch away.

This leads me to conclude the problem is that when I switch away the Keyboard/mouse is essentially disconnected and then (when switching back) reconnected again. Is there any way to get this to still be able to wake the laptop up?

Comment: KVM Switches are not all equal. What is the Model of KVM Switch?  And are you using a very standard Keyboard and Mouse?

Comment: The KVM i got was a chinese make one, specifically [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000765068415.html) , and as to the keyboard and mouse, I believe so yes.

Comment: You will need to ask the supplier for support. Some KVM switches cannot manage what you want. Better (entry level commercial) switches usually can.

Comment: There isnt something at an OS level I can do? It works well enough on OSX (my work PC) and my friend is able to get it working on a linux machine.

Comment: Try updating the Power Drivers on your Windows machines and check the Windows advanced power settings very carefully.

Comment: Where you ever able to get this to work via settings in Windows?

Comment: @AndrewStephens I didnt get much progress on this no, but I may not have dug deep enough to figure it out.

Comment: No problem, I agree the problem seems to be switching away results in the devices being disconnected/unregistered, so they can no longer wake the PC. Seems that some KVMs have ways around this but not others.

Comment: Yeah thats probably it. What bugs me is, mac is able to work around this, and it works to wake the mac up, despite the fact that my macbook is much worse with the KVM otherwise.. but it is what it is :shrug: